# How do I send TCP packets with packETH?

Tags: packet

I want to send packets to `127.0.0.1:11311` with packETH. However, there are some problems I cannot solve.

Here's some screenshots: (click to zoom in)

[image]

[image]

---

1. **In IPv4 data ("Header length")**

   Header length of the packets I want to send is 20. However the "Header length"  only accepts a one digit number. How can I solve this kind of problem?
2. **The packets I want to send didn't specify "TOS"(In IPv4 data) & "urgent pointer"(In TCP data)**

   Are these two arguments important when sending  TCP packets?
3. **In IPv4 data ("options 0x")**

   The TCP data options of the packets I want to send is `0x12`. However it kept showing an error message:

   > Wrong length of tcp options field(length mod 8 must be 0)

   0x12 mod 8 should be zero, I also tried 0x08, 0x00...etc but the error message didn't change.

   I have no idea why this happens, is it relevant to "Header length"?

Comment: The error tells you that the options field must be multiple of 8's. In most cases the TCP packet is 20 bytes with no options field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The IPv4 header length field is interpreted as multiples of 4 octets. IPv4 headers are almost always 20 octets long, so this field's value is almost always 5.
2. Nope, the TOS/DiffServ bits and urgent pointer are usually not important.
3. This field is looking for a value, not a length. When you entered 0x12 or 0x08 or 0x00 thinking you were entering a length, you were actually just entering a single octet value. 1 mod 8 != 0. I'm guessing the packet you were trying to mimic had a 12-octet TCP Timestamp value in there. Also note that the TCP Timestamp option needs to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary from...the start of the TCP headers, if I recall correctly..., so you might need to put some one-octet 0x00 "Nop"/No-op TCP options in there as well, depending on how things align.